# CGAL enumerating/identifying mesh boundaries

Tags: cgal

How does one enumerate/identify mesh boundaries in CGAL?

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2mesh_polyhedral_domain_8cpp-example.html

shows how to read in the bounding polyhedron (defined by vertices and facets) from an off file, but I can't figure out how to associate selected facets with distinct boundary IDs -- this is required in the subsequent finite element analysis where I have to apply different boundary conditions on different parts of the mesh. I've tried to (ab)use the colour information (an additional
optional integer following the vertex connectivity) in the off file but sadly that information gets ignored by CGAL.

Comment: If you load your OFF file into a Surface_mesh instead of a Polyhedron_3 the color information will be stored into a property_map (v:color for the vertex colors, and f:color for the face colors."

Comment: I've noticed the ability to add properties to Surface_meshes, e.g. 

  https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/Surface_mesh_2sm_properties_8cpp-example.html

but I don't think (!) I can then use the resulting Surface_mesh to construct
a 3D Mesh, CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3, or can I? The function 
CGAL::make_mesh_3 requires a CGAL::Polyhedral_mesh_domain_3.
At least that's what I infer from here:

   https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/group__PkgMesh__3Functions.html

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: It is possible to do that, just not very easy. You should look into the demo in CGAL_ROOT/Polyhedron/demo/Polyhedron/Plugins/Mesh_3/mesh_3_plugin.cpp to see how it's done in here, I fear it's the best I can do to help you :/