# CGAL Mesh_3: How to adhere to a surface inside the domain using Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3?

Tags: mesh, cgal, tetrahedra

### The goal

My input is:

- several patches forming the boundary of the domain and
- one or more surface inside the domain.

What I would like to obtain is a tetrahedral mesh that:

1. fills the entire domain,
2. conforms to the interior surface and
3. its boundary vertices have an ID corresponding to their input patch.

One possibility would be to merge the input patches into one mesh and use the example [Remeshing a polyhedral domain with surfaces](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html#title23) from the documentation; this works well but fills only requirements 1 and 2.

Another possibility is, having learnt here how to [keep the patch IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279621/keep-patch-numbers-during-tetrahedral-meshing-with-cgal), to modify the example to use `Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3` instead of `Polyhedral_mesh_domain_with_features_3` so as to have the access to the [constructor with subdomains](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Polyhedral__complex__mesh__domain__3.html#a8337b598d679bd000b08fdbcaeb5f3df). So far, my solution (see below) fills requirements 2 and 3 but *not* 1.

### Code so far

As a simple example, I have split the file **horizons-domain.off** in two; the first file contains the first 10, the second the remaining 2 triangles.

**sides.off**

```
OFF
8 10 0

-1.1855500570497703 -0.076163891881438378 -0.8013403915768772
-1.1855500570497703 0.47597074519009164 -0.8013403915768772
0.79704321809070222 0.47597074519009164 -0.8013403915768772
0.79704321809070222 -0.076163891881438378 -0.8013403915768772
-1.1855500570497703 -0.076163891881438378 1.0953134363531141
-1.1855500570497703 0.47597074519009164 1.0953134363531141
0.79704321809070222 0.47597074519009164 1.0953134363531141
0.79704321809070222 -0.076163891881438378 1.0953134363531141
3  0 1 3
3  3 1 2
3  0 4 1
3  1 4 5
3  3 2 7
3  7 2 6
3  4 0 3
3  7 4 3
3  6 4 7
3  6 5 4
```

**top.off**

```
OFF
4 2 0

-1.1855500570497703 0.47597074519009164 -0.8013403915768772
0.79704321809070222 0.47597074519009164 -0.8013403915768772
-1.1855500570497703 0.47597074519009164 1.0953134363531141
0.79704321809070222 0.47597074519009164 1.0953134363531141
3  0 2 3
3  1 0 3
```

**subdomains.cpp**

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_incremental_builder_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3.h>

#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>

#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedral_complex_mesh_domain_3<K> Mesh_domain;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_polyhedron_3<K>::type Polyhedron;

typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<
    Tr,Mesh_domain::Corner_index,Mesh_domain::Curve_segment_index> C3t3;

using namespace CGAL::parameters;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    // Read patches
    std::cout.precision(17);
    std::cerr.precision(17);

    std::ifstream input1(argv[1]);
    std::ifstream input2(argv[2]);
    std::ifstream input3(argv[3]);

    std::vector<Polyhedron> patches(3);
    input1 >> patches[0];
    input2 >> patches[1];
    input3 >> patches[2];

    // The first mesh is inside subdomain 0, the other two are on the boundary between subdomains 0 and 1.
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> incident_subdomains(3);
    incident_subdomains[0] = std::make_pair(0, 0);
    incident_subdomains[1] = std::make_pair(0, 1);
    incident_subdomains[2] = std::make_pair(0, 1);
    
    Mesh_domain domain(patches.begin(), patches.end(), incident_subdomains.begin(), incident_subdomains.end());

    // Mesh generation
    Mesh_criteria criteria(facet_distance=0.01, cell_radius_edge_ratio = 2);
    C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria, no_perturb(), no_exude());

    // Output
    dump_c3t3(c3t3, "out");
}
```

When I compile and run with

```
> ./subdomains horizons.off sides.off top.off
```

(horizons is the example file from the documentation), the tetrahedra try to conform to the interior surface, keep the IDs but do *not* fill the entire domain:

[image: Results so far]

I also tried changing the line

```
incident_subdomains[0] = std::make_pair(0, 0);
```

to

```
incident_subdomains[0] = std::make_pair(1, 1);
```

This leads to a slightly better result but still far from requirement 3.

[image: improved result]

How can I fix it? I have tried various combinations of 1s and 0s in the `std::pair`s of the subdomains without success.

Comment: You have 3 times `incident_subdomains[0] = ` so `[1]` and `[2]` are not init

Comment: Good catch, thank you. Nonetheless, the problem prevails, I have updated the question.